# Как с помощью регулярных выражений получить адрес биткоин кошелька?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Как с помощью регулярных выражений получить адрес биткоин кошелька?
Вот пример таких адресов: `14NWDXkQwcGN1Pd9fboL8npVynD5SfyJAE`

```
3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r
3Cbq7aT1tY8kMxWLbitaG7yT6bPbKChq64
183hmJGRuTEi2YDCWy5iozY8rZtFwVgahM
1EBHA1ckUWzNKN7BMfDwGTx6GKEbADUozX
```

Comment: ограничители, длина - что т такое есть?

Comment: @EugeneDennis https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Bitcoin_address

Comment: Это 26 - 35 буквенно-цифровых латинских символов (кроме 0, O, I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-z]{26,35}
```

26 - 35 буквенно-цифровых латинских символов (кроме 0, O, I)

Answer (score -2):

Зайди на гитхаб там уже готовый код на реквест и регулярки выражений тоже можешь посмотреть .Генерирует столько кошельков сколько нужно.А если проверка балланса нужна то вот моя тема дополнить хочу тот код. Но не выходит даже через api.
[Как проверить баланс кошелька крипты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257722/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8b)

Вот на гитхабе 1 вариант
https://github.com/PaulGregor/Bitcoin-Keys-Generator

Вариант 2
github.com/MichaelMure/WalletGenerator.net/archive/master.zip

Comment: каким образом написанное вами отвечает на заданный вопрос (про регулярное выражение для извлечения строки)? приводите, пожалуйста, не ссылки, где (возможно) есть ответ, а сам ответ.